# replace values in pandas using regex that matches all values except the provided one

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I want to use regex with pandas to replace values in a column to mark correct answer for the question.
Values in this column are '1943' - the correct one, and other years - incorrect.

The code I have now is:

```
incorrect_dict= {'Q1':{'^(?!1943$).*': 0}}
df = df.replace(incorrect_dict, regex=True)
```

and it doesn't replace values in pandas.

The regex itself seems ok, since it works when I use:

```
string ="1933"
regex = re.compile("^(?!1943$).*")
regex.findall(string)
```

i get:

```
[u'1933']
```

for string = '1943' i get 'No match was found:' so I assume the regex is ok. but when I use if with df.replace the values are not replaced.

thanks for any suggestions

Comment: Can you provide some more context?  Which version of Python are you running?  And what is the `df` object?  I'm not seeing where `incorrect_dict` is being passed to any replace/substitute call.

Comment: I corrected the error in dict names. df is a pandas DataFrame

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the years were parsed as integers. See how it fails:

```
In [17]: df = DataFrame({'Q1': [1933, 1943]})

In [18]: df.replace(incorrect_dict, regex=True)
Out[18]: 
     Q1
0  1933
1  1943
```

But if I convert the years to strings, it works as you expect.

```
In [19]: df['Q1'] = df['Q1'].map(str)

In [20]: df.replace(incorrect_dict, regex=True)
Out[20]: 
     Q1
0     0
1  1943
```

Incidentally, I'm not convinced that treating the responses as strings and using regex is the way to go. Why not take the years as integer and evaluate `df['Q1'] == 1943`? The result will be True/False, meaning correct/incorrect. Seems more useful to me.

Comment: I can't check your answer right now, but the reason I chose to replace values is that I wanted a universal approach and other variables I have are in text format.